# Multiple threads in Java causing problems

Tags: java, multithreading, class, implementation

Sorry for another vague example...but I have a single class where I'm starting a new thread instance. However, if I add a new thread instance, it interrupts (destroys?) the first.

But, if I run two instances of the class (separately, after I turn them into jar files) where each instance only opens up a single thread, they both run concurrently and fine.

I'm convinced the error is the way I'm implementing multi-threading.

Any suggestions for things to look for? Thanks! Sorry for the vague example.

Comment: So because you apologized twice for being vague - you are unable to provide a code sample?

Comment: Monster - In order to avoid vague questions it's usually helpful to create the most simplistic code example that produces the issue you're trying to deal with. Posting such an example is probably the quickest way someone can spot where you're going wrong and suggest an alternative approach.

Comment: I am convinced the error is the way you're implementing multi-threading too. To fix it you should re-implement it correctly. I'm sorry for being so vague about how to fix it, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot assume that an arbitrary class is thread-safe.

Authors of a class **should** be explicit about the thread-safety of their classes, but it's very common that they do not. Given that environments such as Servlets may be intrinsically mulit-threaded this can be a real problem.

You need to study the class and discover which, if any, methods are thread safe. It is possible that the class InstanceOfClassIDontControl has static variables that are getting confused by multithreaded access. If you not only don't control the class, but can't even see its source then you are going to need the owners support.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's an example:

```
public class driver {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Thread x;
        Thread y;

        x = new Thread(new pow());
        y = new Thread(new pow());

        x.start();
        y.start();  
    }
}

public class pow extends Thread {

    public void run() {
        InstanceOfClassIDontControl a = new InstanceOfClassIDontControl();
                a.doVariousProcesses();
    }
}
```

In the example, I (obviously) don't control the class whose instance is created and called in the thread. Each thread may run for minutes. But whenever a concurrent thread is ran (in this case, with y.start()), it destroys the actions of the object called in the run() instance of x.start().

Comment: It sounds like InstanceOfClassIDontControl is not thread safe and uses global, static data structures. I would check the documentation of InstanceOfClassIDontControl.

Comment: But is there no simple way of encapsulating it by itself? I can run as many instances as I want, so long as they are in different running jars.

Comment: Objects do not run in Jars. In normal Java when loading a class all the jars in the classpath are searched and the first definition od a class is loaded. Duplicating the class in many jars will make no difference. The probably answer is to provide a thread-safe wrapper around the non-thread-safe class.